# Check if user is authenticated by Firebase Authentication on the server using PHP?

Tags: firebase-authentication, jwt, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseUI to authenticate users on my website. I have a need for checking if the user is logged in on the server side (in PHP code). How can I accomplish this?

I believe I've seen something about something called JWT, but I don't really understand what I need to do in order to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the Firebase ID token by calling `currentUser.getIdToken()` on the client. You can then send this ID token to your server and verify it before parsing its content and get the user's `uid` from it. Refer to this documentation for verifying ID tokens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library